# How to add class on clicked element but removed from other elements by closest() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to add `.active` class nearer to .table-cell-right class when click on .line class but at same time remove .active class from all other places  by using closest() method in jquery.

```
   <div class="line">
     <div class="table-cell">
       <span class="zky-points">1 ZKY </span><span class="sp-symbol">℗</span>
     </div>
     <div class="table-cell-right">
       <span class="euro">€</span> 1ZKY
       <button name="credit" class="btn btn-primary buy-credit" type="button">Buy Credit<div class="ripple-wrapper"></div></button>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="line">
     <div class="table-cell">
       <span class="zky-points">1 ZKY </span><span class="sp-symbol">℗</span>
     </div>
     <div class="table-cell-right">
       <span class="euro">€</span> 1ZKY
       <button name="credit" class="btn btn-primary buy-credit" type="button">Buy Credit<div class="ripple-wrapper"></div></button>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$(this).find('.active').removeClass('active');` **OR** `$('.active', this).removeClass('active');`

Comment: $('.line').on('click', function(){
$(this).find('.active').removeClass('active');
})

Comment: @kailash Check the DOC regarding `closest()` method, your question doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **don't** need a `closest` function here. Coz you are not changing the parent, instead you are changing a child element. So you need to effectively use `find()`

```
$(".line").click(function () {
    // Remove all the other classes.
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    // Add the correct active class.
    $(this).find('.table-cell').addClass('active');
});
```